# Javascript - Passing pre-defined value

Tags: javascript, function

My function in HTML file is:

```
<p onclick='geturl('http://widefide.com/feed')'> Click Me! </p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Now what should be my javascript function to pass that url (i.e. http://widefide.com/feed) to "demo"? Like this? :

```
function geturl(ok)
{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ok;
}
```

This is returning this error: "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } "
Is this because thar

element is getting url from PHP+MYSQL? For instance:

```
print("<p onclick='geturl('" . $title["url"] . "')'>Click Me!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should be (note the quotes):

```
<p onclick="geturl('http://widefide.com/feed')"> Click Me! </p>
```

And the JavaScript function should be:

```
function geturl(url){
   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = url;
}
```

```js
function geturl(url){
       document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = url;
    }
```

```html
<p onclick="geturl('http://widefide.com/feed')"> Click Me! </p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked :D
Can I assign that value to x in this function? Like:

function geturl(url) {
    x = url;
}

And them call that function in another function to get url? :)

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, then yes. You just need to define `x` outside of both functions first.

Comment: When I ran this code here, it worked. But in my code, it didn't and JavaScript console returned "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " :/ #DifferentStory

Comment: Sounds like a typo but without an example to look at I could only guess.

Comment: Added more code in my original post for reference :)

Comment: Also, it's working fine here (when running code snippet in stackoverflow). But it doesn't work @ [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: One problem in the code you changed in your question above is the quotes in `<p onclick='geturl('http://widefide.com/feed')'>`. You're mixing quote styles. Use either `<p onclick="geturl('http://widefide.com/feed')">` or `<p onclick='geturl("http://widefide.com/feed")'>`. Change your PHP to `print("<p onclick='geturl(\"" . $title["url"] . "\")'>Click Me!</p>`

Comment: Hey thanks. I changed my PHP to the code mentioned by you and It worked. Thanks a ton for helping me learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Better avoid inline event handlers, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

To write the url in `#demo`, you can use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) to get it, and then set the content using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo'),
    els = document.getElementsByClassName("geturl-trigger");
function geturl() {
  var url = this.dataset.url;
  demo.textContent = url;
}
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) els[i].addEventListener('click', geturl);
```

```html
<p class="geturl-trigger" data-url="http://widefide.com/feed">Click Me!</p>
<p class="geturl-trigger" data-url="http://example.com">Click Me!</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```